# RootViewController transition effect does not work

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation, uiscenedelegate

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let protectionVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "PrivacyProtectionViewController")
    
    guard let windowScene = self.window?.windowScene else {
        return
    }
    
    privacyProtectionWindow = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
    privacyProtectionWindow?.rootViewController = protectionVC
    UIView.transition(with: privacyProtectionWindow!, duration: 1.2, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: nil, completion: nil)
    privacyProtectionWindow?.windowLevel = .alert + 1
    privacyProtectionWindow?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

When I put this to sceneWillResignActive function in SceneDelegate.swift,
it does not affect my transition style at all.

Do you have any idea why it does not work?!

Comment: can you illustrate more about your question and what you want to achieve by putting code on sceneWillResignActive.. you know when that method gets called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `UIView.transition` method will not work because you are animating the the window and not the controller's view which is being viewed on screen. Your animation duration (1.2 seconds) is also too long.

When the user resigns from the current scene, the iOS animations occurs faster than 1 second. You might see it when switching between apps, but when moving to the home screen the animation occurs almost instantly.

With all these considerations, you might be able to get the desired result with the following code.

```swift
privacyProtectionWindow = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
privacyProtectionWindow?.rootViewController = protectionVC

privacyProtectionWindow?.windowLevel = UIWindow.Level.alert
privacyProtectionWindow?.makeKeyAndVisible()

// New animation code
protectionVC.view.alpha = 0.0
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, options: [.curveEaseOut]) {
    protectionVC.view.alpha = 1.0
}
```

Also, for additional smoothness you can add animation when the scene becomes active again.

```swift
func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
        self.privacyProtectionWindow?.rootViewController!.view.alpha = 0.0
    } completion: { (completed) in
        if completed{
            self.privacyProtectionWindow = nil
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }
}
```

The animation of `alpha` values change `UIView` opacity. It will give you the effect you are going for with the `UIView.transition` method.

Comment: Hey… where did you learn this from?! It works…